# How can I used aggregate to fetch items inside nested documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have two documents inside a collection that has nested arrays:

```
{
      faculty: '2019-00001-FC-0',
      sections: [
        {
          section: 'DEET 3-1',
          date: '04-19-2022',
          subject: 'Integrated Circuits',
          attendance: [
            {
              number: '2019-00005-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00006-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00007-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00015-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00016-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00018-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00019-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00020-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-14614-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

and

```
{
      faculty: '2019-00002-FC-0',
      sections: [
        {
          section: 'DEET 3-1',
          date: '04-19-2022',
          subject: 'Integrated Circuits',
          attendance: [
            {
              number: '2019-00005-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00006-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00007-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00015-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00016-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00018-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00019-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-00020-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            },
            {
              number: '2019-14614-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have been using find and aggregate to fetch the specific values inside the nested arrays with:

```
db.attendances.aggregate({
  $project: {
    sections: {
      $filter: {
        input: '$sections',
        as: 's',
        cond: {
          $and: [
            {
              $eq: ['$$s.section', 'DEET 3-1'],
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But whenever I nest the code to go deeper in the array it doesn't work.

I want the output print out'2019-000005-MN-0' from different documents like:

```
{
      faculty: '2019-00001-FC-0',
      sections: [
        {
          section: 'DEET 3-1',
          date: '04-19-2022',
          subject: 'Integrated Circuits',
          attendance: [
            {
              number: '2019-00005-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

and

```
{
      faculty: '2019-00002-FC-0',
      sections: [
        {
          section: 'DEET 3-1',
          date: '04-19-2022',
          subject: 'Integrated Circuits',
          attendance: [
            {
              number: '2019-00005-MN-0',
              status: 'Present'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Is there a way to do this or something similar? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- because you have nested array you need nested `map/filter`
- for the nested you need filter to keep just the `attendance` with the number
- for the outer array you need map, not filter because you want not just keep some member, but you want to change them
- the outer map replaces the `sections` that dont match with null
  and if match, they go nested and filter the `attendance`
- we need one last filter on `sections` to remove those nulls

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=625eb8f68b39bcf74dae2740)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"sections": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$sections",
        "as": "s",
        "in": 
         {"$cond": 
           [{"$eq": ["$$s.section", "DEET 3-1"]},
             {"$mergeObjects": 
               ["$$s",
                 {"attendance": 
                   {"$filter": 
                     {"input": "$$s.attendance",
                      "as": "a",
                      "cond": {"$eq": ["$$a.number", "2019-00005-MN-0"]}}}}]},
            null]}}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"sections": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$sections", "cond": {"$ne": ["$sections", null]}}}}}])
```